# Serve classes AND static content from other project

Tags: java, servlets, jar, war, static-content

I have a Dynamic Web Project with the following structure:

```
Project1
|-- src
|    '-- com
|         '-- example1
|              '-- Servlet1.java
|-- WebContent
|     |-- WEB-INF
|     |     '-- web.xml
|     '-- index1.html
'-- pom.xml
```

And another Project with the following structure:

```
Project2
|-- src
|   '-- example2
|        '-- Servlet2.java
|-- resources
|   '-- index2.html
'-- pom.xml
```

I want to deploy Project1 on Tomcat and Project1 should use the Servlet2 and index2.html from Project2.
I was able to use Servlet2.java by adding Project2 to Project1's Deployment Assembly as a .jar, however this way I couldn't access index2.html.

I was able to access index2.html (by URL: .../contextroot/index2.html) when deploying Project1 by adding the following to the pom.xml of Project1:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Project2</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <type>war</type>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

However this way the Project2 is no longer added to Project1's Deployment Assembly as a .jar but as a .war so I can't use Servlet2 anymore.

How can I import Project2 into Project1 so that I can use both the Servlet2 and index2.html?

Comment: Since you have a pom file, in maven, preserve the build contents. Normally, it automatically deletes them when it creates the final target. That would preserve the jar file. Then you could use that in project 2.

Comment: I think it's on https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/examples/skipping-clean.html